# Non deterministic testing in Scala

Tags: scala, unit-testing

I have a few methods that returns non-deterministic results in matter of arrange inside an array/set. The content will always be the same, and I'd like to test the content itself, not the way they're arranged.

**Example: I have a Set input and I want to separate them accordingly to the name (this is not the exact method, but it's very similar.**

Input = `Set(Object A1, Object B1, Object A2, Object C1, Object C2)`

So, the expected output would be something like that:

`Array(Set(Object A1, Object A2), Set(Object B1), Set(Object C1, Object C2))`

But when I was testing it, I realized the output varies, and because of that, I cannot use a deterministic like `shouldBe` approach

Other possible outputs examples:

1. `Array(Set(Object B1), Set(Object A1, Object A2), Set(Object C1, Object C2))`
2. `Array(Set(Object B1), Set(Object A2, Object A1), Set(Object C2, Object C1))`
3. `Array(Set(Object C2, Object C1), Set(Object B1), Set(Object A2, Object A1))`

...

Is there any approach that I could use to check it's content, knowing that they may change inside the Array and also inside the Set?

Thank you

Comment: `sameElementsAs`?

Comment: I think it wouldn't work since the `sets` may be arranged differently, for example: `Set(A, B)` or `Set(B, A)` at the same time the `array` itself may arrange the `sets` in a different order, example: `Array(Set(A), Set(B))` or `Array(Set(B), Set(A))`

Comment: `Sets` don't have order `Set(A, B)` is the same as `Set(B, A)` - Actually, if you know the `Array` will not contain duplicates you can just `toSet` it and use that for the comparison.

Comment: @LuisMiguelMejíaSuárez I actually went for your second suggestion, I made both arrays (result and expected) as sets and it work nicely. Would you like to make this an anwser, so that I can choose it? Thank you

Comment: I believe this is a duplicate that I am too lazy to find.